# How to open new popup window after time delay

Tags: javascript, popup

I am creating Canvas based app, User can share his creation on facebook by clicking share button, for this I need to save images to my AWS server after that I need to open FB Share popup window. Any guesses how can I open popup window after timeInterval

Comment: Why does it have to be on an interval? Shouldn't the upload tell you when it is done so than you can make you next step?

Comment: ya I think opening popup with time interval is not possible so I am trying second approach I open popup instantly when user clicks on share button and it shows preload animation with text please wait while data is uplading, once it done I need to change popup with FB.UI object to share but Unable to do that.... any idea how to change text to fb object???

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are asking for. I would open that window after you receive some response from your server. But if you want to set a delay you could easily use an interval, like this:

```
function saveImageAndShare() {

  // code to contact your server for saving the image

  ....

  function openShareWindow() {
   window.open('your-share-url');
   clearInterval(myIntervalId) 
  }
  var myIntervalId = setInterval(openShareWindow, 3000);
}
saveImageAndShare()
```

Comment: J Linderbro, Actually I am sharing on facebooky dynamically, user can share what he made on canvas, so for that on first step I need to save that on server and when I recieve callback popup should open to share on FB, but I think open popup by timedelay is not possible so I am trying second approch, Once user click on share button it open popup instantly it contains preloading animation to uploading data for user and when I got callback I need to update this popup to FB.UI object.... I am stuck here, unable to change content... any clue how to update content???

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following you here, what the actual problem is. Is it the upload delay or is this a redirect problem?

Comment: Anyways I have change the workflow... anyways problem is when we try to open popup after some delay like 2-3 seconds then browser dosen't let it open...